# Chef and application deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, chef-infra

How is it possible to keep my rails application up to date using chef?

While reading documentation I understood how to set up servers from scratch using `knife bootstrap`. But is it possible to run another tasks after this?

Earlier I have used capistrano but now we have two staging and ten production servers which needs to be up to date when new version of the application is released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do is to look at the built in [Deploy resource](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Deploy+Resource)

You might also want to look at the [Application cookbook](http://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/tree/master/application). This is a bit harder to grok, but it lets you deploy an application driven off a databag.

Answer (score 1):

I found new gem on this topic:

https://github.com/iain/roundsman - it's capistrano + chef-solo integrated